# Msgbox and vbyesnocancel

Tags: vb.net

Good day to all, i was having some trouble with my msgbox prompting with vbyesnocancel

• This code everything is working just fine "BUT" i needed to click multiple yes, no, cancel to activate its function

```
Private Sub cbEnableDeductions_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbEnableDeductions.Click
            If MsgBox("Do You want To Enable deductions?", vbYesNoCancel) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                cbEnableDeductions.Checked = True
                txtSSS.Enabled = True
                txtHDMF.Enabled = True
                txtPhilHealth.Enabled = True
            ElseIf MsgBox("Do You want To Enable deductions?", vbYesNoCancel) = MsgBoxResult.No Then
                cbEnableDeductions.Checked = True
                Total()
            ElseIf MsgBox("Do You want To Enable deductions?", vbYesNoCancel) = MsgBoxResult.Cancel Then
                cbEnableDeductions.CheckState = False
            End If
        End Sub
```

• with this code "NO" and "CANCEL" functions are not working

```
 Private Sub cbEnableDeductions_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbEnableDeductions.Click
        If MsgBox("Do You want To Enable deductions?", vbYesNoCancel) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            cbEnableDeductions.Checked = True
            txtSSS.Enabled = True
            txtHDMF.Enabled = True
            txtPhilHealth.Enabled = True
        ElseIf vbYesNoCancel = MsgBoxResult.No Then
            cbEnableDeductions.Checked = True
            Total()
        ElseIf vbYesNoCancel = MsgBoxResult.Cancel Then
            cbEnableDeductions.CheckState = False
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: You really should use MessageBox.Show() instead of the legacy MsgBox() function.  I've seen subtle bugs with MsgBox where the dialog would not properly appear in front of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, you are asking the input for 3 times with your existing code.

```
 Dim result As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("Do You want To Enable deductions?", vbYesNoCancel)
    If result = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        cbEnableDeductions.Checked = True
        txtSSS.Enabled = True
        txtHDMF.Enabled = True
        txtPhilHealth.Enabled = True
    ElseIf result = MsgBoxResult.No Then
        cbEnableDeductions.Checked = True
        Total()
    ElseIf result = MsgBoxResult.Cancel Then
        cbEnableDeductions.CheckState = False
    End If
```

or you can use a CASE

```
 Select Case MsgBox("Do You want To Enable deductions?", vbYesNoCancel)
    Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
       cbEnableDeductions.Checked = True
       txtSSS.Enabled = True
       txtHDMF.Enabled = True
       txtPhilHealth.Enabled = True
    Case MsgBoxResult.No
       cbEnableDeductions.Checked = True
       Total()
    Case MsgBoxResult.Cancel
       cbEnableDeductions.CheckState = False
 End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Private Sub cbEnableDeductions_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbEnableDeductions.Click

    Dim msgBoxResult = MsgBox("Do You want To Enable deductions?", vbYesNoCancel)

    If msgBoxResult = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        cbEnableDeductions.Checked = True
        txtSSS.Enabled = True
        txtHDMF.Enabled = True
        xtPhilHealth.Enabled = True

     ElseIf msgBoxResult = MsgBoxResult.No Then
         cbEnableDeductions.Checked = True
         Total()

     ElseIf msgBoxResult = MsgBoxResult.Cancel Then
         cbEnableDeductions.CheckState = False

     End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: ohh i cant i needed 15 Rep points sorry sir im only new here at stackoverflow